# Setting PHPMyAdmin Language

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

The user interface for phpmyadmin is displayed in german for some reason and i'd like to change it to english but don't know how. I installed the latest xampp.

Thanks

Answer (score 85, accepted):

At the first site is a dropdown field to select the language of phpmyadmin.

In the config.inc.php you can set:

```
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

More details you can find in the documentation: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/

Comment: Thanks very much mate. I deserve a big smack in the head! it was right in front of me :(

Comment: @Mahie You deserve no smack at all, it’s not in the most obvious place, I missed it too.

Answer (score 57):

In `config.inc.php` in the top-level directory, set

```
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8'; // Language if no other language is recognized
// or
$cfg['Lang'] = 'en-utf-8'; // Force this language for all users
```

If `Lang` isn't set, you should be able to select the language in the initial welcome screen, and the language your browser prefers should be preselected there.

Comment: I'm using version 3.4.5, couldn't find it in the config.inc.php

Comment: @Mahie You can still set it, even if it's not present in the default configuration ;)

Comment: If those two lines are not present then add it in the config file. It worked for me.

Comment: $cfg['Lang']  = 'en'; worked for me!

Answer (score 16):

sounds like you downloaded the [german xampp package](http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp-windows.html) instead of the [english xampp package](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) (yes, it's another download-link) where the language is set according to the package you loaded. to change the language afterwards, simply edit the `config.inc.php` and set:

```
$cfg['Lang'] = 'en-utf-8';
```

Comment: $cfg['Lang'] = 'en';
this setting worked for me also.