# Wamp Server phpMyAdmin not in English

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

phpMyAdmin is in FRANÇAIS or something and I don't know how to get it to English. I have uninstalled it and reinstalled it with no luck. I downloaded it from the Wamp Server **English site**: http://www.wampserver.com/en/ But phpMyAdmin is still not in English.

Does anyone know how I can change the language? I can't even read the page to find settings and Google Chrome won't translate the iframes (and phpMyAdmin is full of iframes)

**Also I have searched around and I have not been able to find any solutions.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528972/changing-the-language-of-phpmyadmin-from-german-to-english

Comment: @UdoHeld - Nope, that is XAMPP not Wamp Server. Two different programs.

Comment: Both are about phpMyAdmin configuration ... . Why don't you try the accepted answer?

Comment: @UdoHeld I can't find `config.inc.php`. Do you know where that file is? It isn't anywhere in the Wamp Server control panel.

Comment: I guess its not on the Server control panel. You should search your Wamp installation folder for it.

Comment: I found the config file and added `$cfg['Lang'] = 'en-utf-8';` and it works. Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [WAMP/MySQL errors not in correct language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802970/wamp-mysql-errors-not-in-correct-language)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is some other installed languages on your system that caused this problem.
However you can change phpMyAdmin inside its settings. To fix it, please do these steps (As you can't read the texts, I have to tell you an address in phpMyAdmin) :

> This is for phpMyAdmin 3.4.5; You may have another version

1. Open phpMyAdmin
2. In the home page, look at the main menu in top of the page (right side)
3. Point your mouse on the last item; A list will be shown to you, then click at the last item with a wrench icon beside it. (You entered to the phpMyAdmin settings)
4. There are 4 boxes in the current page. Look at the right-bottom one. There is a button there. It's reset button. Click on it ...
5. Your settings will reset and you can see phpMyAdmin in English language.

Good luck.

Answer (score 16):

## **Solutions for both part:**

**1) change main language of Phpmyadmin:**
open PHPMYADMIN homepage, and in the center, there is Language Dropdown. (or insert `$cfg['Lang'] = 'en-utf-8';` in `\apps\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php` )

**2) change MYSQL panel language:**

(according to [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802970/wamp-mysql-errors-not-in-correct-language) post):
Open **my.ini** (located in **/bin/mysql/mysqlX.XX/** ) and change 

`lc-messages=fr_FR` 

to 

`lc-messages=en_GB`

Comment: #2 works for me. You have to restart all services after that.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a french project, so maybe its actually configured to french settings. Have a look at [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html). Its a WAMP stack as well.

Searching on SO: [Setting PHPMyAdmin Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528972/changing-the-language-of-phpmyadmin-from-german-to-english)

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded XAMPP before but maybe it was in German then also because I still had WAMPSERVER installed. I'll try XAMPP [again].

Answer (score 1):

Open Your PHP MyAdmin and show this screenshot

[image]