# About the displaying language in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin software, it displays another language when occur errors.I cannot understand this as I'm used English.
Please help me to fix this problem, I select collation as utf8_general_ci by referring a tutorial. But when I select it, it changes to utf8mb4_general_ci. I don't know the exact meaning of using collation. Please help me, I really appreciate your help.I'm new to JDBC.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wamp Server phpMyAdmin not in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542961/wamp-server-phpmyadmin-not-in-english)

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate to me because the phpMyAdmin interface is in English here, it's the error messages coming back from MySQL that aren't.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin and MySQL versions do you use?

Comment: Can you show us the output of the query `show variables like "%lc%";` ?