# phpmyadmin datepicker starting day of week

Tags: phpmyadmin

please, do you have any idea, how to change datepicker in PhpMyAdmin (4.5.0.2) to show calendar which uses Monday as first day of week? In standard way, there is Sunday and I search everywhere in settings, but not found this one.

Comment: Try configuring locale properties.Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528972/setting-phpmyadmin-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no setting for this, but here is the patch for 4.5.0.2:

```
diff --git a/js/functions.js b/js/functions.js
index 5e6e9d6..efc8319 100644
--- a/js/functions.js
+++ b/js/functions.js
@@ -1249,7 +1249,8 @@ function addDateTimePicker() {
             PMA_addDatepicker($(this), type, {
                 showMillisec: showMillisec,
                 showMicrosec: showMicrosec,
-                timeFormat: timeFormat
+                timeFormat: timeFormat,
+                firstDay: 1
             });
         });
     }
```

Comment: there are new versions of phpMyAdmin and feature for switching first day of week is still not included :( I'm still had to change it manually.

Comment: I did not see this as a general enough request to implement it in the code, but feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it's implemented it in version 5.1.1

In Server settings -> Features -> General -> First Day calendar field Monday is selected as the first day but when clicking on the calendar, Sunday still appears as the first day.

You have to configure the file `config.inc.php` and add `$cfg['FirstDayOfCalendar'] = 1;`